# Defining a periodic function with the floor function

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to define the function defined in the following image using the floor function? If so, how?

I am using the Symbolic Toolbox in Matlab, which will take the Laplace Transform of the floor function in some examples I've tried.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it will fit your need, but here is a function that does that:

```
f = @(x) (0.5 - abs(x-floor(x)-0.5))*2
x = linspace(0,10, 1000);
plot(x, f(x))
```

[image]

You need an `abs` somewhere because the sign of the slope changes, so `floor` cannot do it that its own. The remaining is about getting the proper scaling.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Perfect. I've done some searching online for tutorials that guide me through a number of graphing examples using the floor function, but I've been unsuccessful. Can anyone give me a link where I can find numerous examples of periodic functions using the floor command? Thanks.